# Flask paramaters can´t take special character (>=, ==, <, etc...)

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask function that takes 2 pandas columnas and compare them with this posible operations: >=, <=, ==, <, >.

This is the request in Postman with the given parameters:
[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvjg9.png)

The problem is that the request:

```
localhost:5000/dependencia?db=database&table=table_A&dateCol=date_column&column1=column_B&column2=column_C&operation=>=
```

gives an error because of the last parameter:

```
operation=>=
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour @ https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what's the problem but maybe you're looking for a mapping:

```
import operator

str_to_operation = {"<=": operator.le, "==": operator.eq}
# or:
str_to_operation = {"<=": lambda a, b: a <= b, "==": lambda a, b: a == b}

operation = "<="

print(str_to_operation[operation](1, 2))
```

Comment: If a give the operation <= to the parameter like a string ("<="), it doesn't work either.

Comment: maybe you need to encode "<=" in the request: "%3C%3D"